# How Can I Assign an Expression To a Model Property Then Use It In a Partial For an ActionLInk?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, lambda

Is it possible to assign an Lambda Expression (action?) to a property of my View Model, then use that expression in a Partial? What should the model's property type be? Psuedo Code:

**View Model**

```
public class MyModel
{
    public ????? MyAction {get;set;}
}
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   var model = new MyModel();
   model.MyAction = ?????<MyController>(x => x.DoThis());

   return View(model);
}

public ActionResult DoThis()
{
   return View();
}
```

**Partial.ascx**, How would I assign the action to the ActionLink?

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<MyModel>" %>

<%=Html.ActionLink<Controller>(x => x.DoThis())%>
```

I am using the strongly typed ActionLink from the Futures assembly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public class MyModel
{
    Expression<Action<MyController>> Action { get; set; }
}

...

model.Action = x => x.DoThis();

...

<%= Html.ActionLink( Model.Action ) %>
```

Comment: That makes sense, but doesn't that hold true to the strongly typed ActionLink in general? Aren't they including that in the 2.0?

Comment: Ok.  I think I misread what you were trying to do.  I thought you were trying to run some code in the controller to get back the function that is used to generate the link.  I'll update.

Comment: What if I don't know the Controller type? Can MyController be generic?

Comment: Sorry for expanding, but what if DoThis has arguments with values that are not known until runtime? ex: DoThis(int id);

Comment: You could use an interface or base controller but you'd only be able to access the methods in the interface or that are defined by the base class.  I think that the variables will be captured by the lambda and will have their final values when the expression is evaluated.  Use a temp variable if the values will change after the action is assigned.